# Sending Several Queries in RxTx

Tags: java, scala, rxtx

I'm trying to send several queries at once to a device (car's ECU, specifically the [ELM327](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ELM327)) via RxTx. Here's the class that utilize RxTx:

```
import collection.JavaConversions._
import gnu.io._
import java.io._
import java.util.TooManyListenersException

class Serial private (portName: String, 
                      baudRate: Int, 
                      dataBits: Int, 
                      stopBits: Int, 
                      parity: Int, 
                      flowControl: Int) {

  private val portId = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier(portName)
  private val serial = portId.open("Serial Connection from OBDScan", 
                                   5000).asInstanceOf[SerialPort]
  setPortParameters(baudRate, dataBits, stopBits, parity, flowControl)

  private val istream = serial.getInputStream
  private val ostream = serial.getOutputStream

  def this(portName: String, baudRate: Int = 115200) = this(portName, baudRate,
    SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
    SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
    SerialPort.PARITY_NONE,
    SerialPort.FLOWCONTROL_NONE)

  def close = {
    try {
      istream.close
      ostream.close
    } catch {
      case ioe: IOException => // don't care, it's ended already
    }

    serial.close
  }

  def query(command: String) = {
    ostream.write(command.getBytes)
    ostream.write("\r\n".getBytes) // neccessary for Serial port.
  }

  def queryResult: String = {
    try {
      val availableBytes = istream.available
      val buffer = new Array[Byte](availableBytes)

      if (availableBytes > 0) {
        istream.read(buffer, 0, availableBytes)
      }
      new String(buffer, 0, availableBytes)
    } catch {
      case ioe: IOException => "Something wrong! Please try again."
    }
  }

  def addListener(listener: SerialPortEventListener) = {
    try {
      serial.addEventListener(listener)
      serial.notifyOnDataAvailable(true)
    } catch {
      case tm: TooManyListenersException => println("Too many listener")
    }
  }

  def removeListener = {
    serial.removeEventListener
  }

  private def setPortParameters(br: Int, 
                                db: Int, 
                                sb: Int, 
                                p: Int, 
                                fc: Int) = {
    serial.setSerialPortParams(baudRate, dataBits, stopBits, parity)
    serial.setFlowControlMode(flowControl)
  }
}

object Serial {
  def connect(portName: String, baudRate: Int = 115200): Serial = {
    try {
      val ret = new Serial(portName, baudRate)
      ret
    } catch {
      // exception handling omitted.
    }
  }
}
```

Now querying works fine and gives me the correct result. The problems comes when I sent several queries at once:

```
val serial = Serial.connect("COM34")
serial.query("AT Z")
serial.query("10 00")
```

The device recieved both of the queries, but returns only one result. If I want to get the next result, I have to send another query, which will results in the program get late by one query. If I call `Thread.sleep` after each query:

```
val serial = Serial.connect("COM34")
serial.query("AT Z")
Thread.sleep(500)
serial.query("10 00")
```

The problem's solved, but of course the entire application stops when `Thread.sleep` is called. I don't want this since the application will do this query all the time (which means it will hangs all the time if I do this).

Since I'm on Scala, I'm thinking on using Actors or something similar, but I think it's an overkill for a desktop application. Is there any way to do this without Actors? Maybe I'm reading the response from serial port wrong?

**TL;DR:** I want to do several queries to serial device via RxTx without locking the whole application (current solution achieved via `Thread.sleep`, which blocks the whole application). How can I do that?